Metro Error when Running Expo start after creation of new expo app
Im receiving a Metro Error after creating an expo app. I do not change anything prior to running. I use npx create-expo-app <MyApp>, then run npx expo start and receive an error. I've tried removing node_modules and package.json and reinstalling. Nothing seems to work.
This is the error I receive in my terminal:
Call Stack
  <unknown> (.)

Metro error: Unable to resolve module .\node_modules\expo-router\entry from C:\Users\parys\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Test\test2/.: .\node_modules\expo-router\entry could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ..\..\..\..\..\node_modules

This is the error I receive on the localhost:
Static Rendering Error (Node.js)
Unable to resolve module .\node_modules\expo-router\entry from C:\Users\parys\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Test\test2/.: .\node_modules\expo-router\entry could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ..\..\..\..\..\node_modules

I've ensured the expo router has the correct path. Remove the node_modules and package.json and reinstall with npm install.
